# OpenLayer draw remove shape after drawend

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using basic example cant add element on map
After drawend event its disapear
in drawend listener element is present
Using code from default example page gives same result

```
private map: OlMap;
  private drawSource: VectorSource = new VectorSource({
    wrapX: false
  });
  private drawLayer: VectorLayer<VectorSource> = new VectorLayer({
    source: this.drawSource
  });
  private raster =  new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM()
  });    
  private drawAction: Draw;
  private snap: Snap;    
  constructor() {
  }    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
    this.startDraw();
  }    
  private initMap(): void {

    const mapCentre: number[] =  fromLonLat(this.defaultMapCenter);

    this.map = new OlMap({
      layers: [
        this.drawLayer,
        this.raster
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new View({
        center: mapCentre,
        zoom: 8, maxZoom: 22,
      }),
      controls: [],
    });
    this.map.addLayer(basemapLayer);
    })
  }
private startDraw() {
    this.drawAction = new Draw({
      source: this.drawSource,
      type: 'Polygon'
    });

    this.map.addInteraction(this.drawAction);
    this.snap = new Snap({source: this.drawSource});
    this.map.addInteraction(this.snap)
```

})
}

Before drawend
[image: Before drawend]

After
[image: After drawend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layer order so the drawn features are not hidden beneath the raster

```
  layers: [
    this.raster,
    this.drawLayer
  ],
```